# Gundo plugin requires python 2.4 when version 2.7 is installed

Tags: plugin-system, version

I have Python 2.7.9 installed. And now I get the message that the Gundo plugin requires 2.4. Is there a workaround?

Here is my vimrc file:

```
set nocompatible              " be iMproved, required
filetype off                  " required

" set the runtime path to include Vundle and initialize
set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim
call vundle#begin()
" alternatively, pass a path where Vundle should install plugins
"call vundle#begin('~/some/path/here')

" let Vundle manage Vundle, required

Plugin 'VundleVim/Vundle.vim'
Plugin 'tpope/vim-surround'
Plugin 'easymotion/vim-easymotion'
Plugin 'scrooloose/nerdtree'
Plugin 'jlanzarotta/bufexplorer'
Plugin 'rstacruz/sparkup'
Plugin 'MarcWeber/vim-addon-mw-utils'
Plugin 'tomtom/tlib_vim'
Plugin 'jeffkreeftmeijer/vim-numbertoggle'
Plugin 'scrooloose/syntastic'
Plugin 'qpkorr/vim-renamer'
Plugin 'klen/python-mode'
Plugin 'ctrlpvim/ctrlp.vim'
Plugin 'dhruvasagar/vim-table-mode'
Plugin 'shinokada/listtrans.vim'
Plugin 'gavinbeatty/vmath.vim'
Plugin 'sjl/gundo.vim'
Plugin 'tpope/vim-abolish'


" Bindings for Listtrans plugin
nmap  ;l   :call ListTrans_toggle_format()<CR>          
vmap  ;l   :call ListTrans_toggle_format('visual')<CR>

" Bindings for Gundo
nnoremap <F5> :GundoToggle<CR>

"_Bindings for vmath
"nmap          ++  vip++
"vmap          ++  VMATH_YankAndAnalyse()                     


" All of your Plugins must be added before the following line
call vundle#end()            " required
filetype plugin indent on    " required
" To ignore plugin indent changes, instead use:
"filetype plugin on
"
" Brief help
" :PluginList       - lists configured plugins
" :PluginInstall    - installs plugins; append `!` to update or just :PluginUpdate
" :PluginSearch foo - searches for foo; append `!` to refresh local cache
" :PluginClean      - confirms removal of unused plugins; append `!` to auto-approve removal
"
" see :h vundle for more details or wiki for FAQ
" Put your non-Plugin stuff after this line

:syntax on
let NERDTreeQuitOnOpen=1

:set hlsearch
```

---

```
vim --version
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4 (2013 Aug 10, compiled Mar 31 2015 23:56:29)
Included patches: 1-488, 576
Modified by pkg-vim-maintainers@lists.alioth.debian.org
Compiled by buildd@
Huge version without GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
+acl             +farsi           +mouse_netterm   +syntax
+arabic          +file_in_path    +mouse_sgr       +tag_binary
+autocmd         +find_in_path    -mouse_sysmouse  +tag_old_static
-balloon_eval    +float           +mouse_urxvt     -tag_any_white
-browse          +folding         +mouse_xterm     -tcl
++builtin_terms  -footer          +multi_byte      +terminfo
+byte_offset     +fork()          +multi_lang      +termresponse
+cindent         +gettext         -mzscheme        +textobjects
-clientserver    -hangul_input    +netbeans_intg   +title
-clipboard       +iconv           +path_extra      -toolbar
+cmdline_compl   +insert_expand   -perl            +user_commands
+cmdline_hist    +jumplist        +persistent_undo +vertsplit
+cmdline_info    +keymap          +postscript      +virtualedit
+comments        +langmap         +printer         +visual
+conceal         +libcall         +profile         +visualextra
+cryptv          +linebreak       -python          +viminfo
+cscope          +lispindent      -python3         +vreplace
+cursorbind      +listcmds        +quickfix        +wildignore
+cursorshape     +localmap        +reltime         +wildmenu
+dialog_con      -lua             +rightleft       +windows
+diff            +menu            -ruby            +writebackup
+digraphs        +mksession       +scrollbind      -X11
-dnd             +modify_fname    +signs           -xfontset
-ebcdic          +mouse           +smartindent     -xim
+emacs_tags      -mouseshape      -sniff           -xsmp
+eval            +mouse_dec       +startuptime     -xterm_clipboard
+ex_extra        +mouse_gpm       +statusline      -xterm_save
+extra_search    -mouse_jsbterm   -sun_workshop    -xpm
   system vimrc file: "$VIM/vimrc"
     user vimrc file: "$HOME/.vimrc"
 2nd user vimrc file: "~/.vim/vimrc"
      user exrc file: "$HOME/.exrc"
  fall-back for $VIM: "/usr/share/vim"
Compilation: gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H     -g -O2 -fPIE -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1      
Linking: gcc   -fPIE -pie -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -Wl,--as-needed -o vim        -lm -ltinfo -lnsl  -lselinux -lacl -lattr -lgpm -ldl
```

Comment: Do you mean that Gundo doesn't work with your Python version? I believe it requires _at least_ Python 2.4, but should work with any Python 2.4+. Seems to be working with `2.7.6` in my machine.

Comment: It does indeed say that it requires 2.4+ but it still doesn't make sense.

Comment: How so? If it doesn't work and displays this message as an error explanation, then there's something wrong with your setup (Gundo doesn't communicate properly with Python, or at least not with this specific implementation you installed). If it works, it's just an information that you can't use Gundo with Python older than 2.4 (which is _very_ old itself). Where exactly is this Python version requirement displayed?

Comment: What is your Vim version? Please show `:version` output

Comment: The python error message is  displayed after I have used the F5-key to start gundo. That is why I have posted my .vimrc plugin.

Comment: After pressing F5, I get this message: "E117: Unknown function: gundo#GundoToggle." After pressing F5 again, I get the message: "Gundo requires Vim to be compiled with Python 2.4+ "

Comment: You have **-python** You need a Vim with **+python** or **+python/dyn**. Try installing vim-gtk from your package manager.

Comment: That did  the job. Thanks for your patience and your answer, Christian Brabandt.

Answer (score 8):

Try the [undotree plugin](https://github.com/mbbill/undotree/):

> Someone asked me about the difference with Gundo, here is a list of
>   differences, or advantages.
>
> 1. **Pure vimscript implementation and no 3rd-party libraries(like python) is needed**, don't worry about performance, it's not such a big
>      deal for vim to handle this. The only dependency is the 'diff' tool
>      which always shipped with vim and even without 'diff' you still can
>      use most of the features of this script.
> 2. Realtime updated undo tree. Once you make changes, the undo tree will be updated simultaneously.
> 3. Several useful marks, like current changeset, next redo changeset, saved changeset, etc.
> 4. Toggle between relative timestamp and absolute timestamp.
> 5. Realtime updated undo window.
> 6. Ability to clear undo history.
> 7. More customizable.

I've switched from Gundo to undotree about some years ago and it works very well.

Answer (score 6):

Add this to your .vimrc

```
if has('python3')
    let g:gundo_prefer_python3 = 1
endif
```

I was getting similar error. The above worked for me (I am using Manjaro Linux, and installed community/python-neovim (Python 3 client for neovim)). Found at https://bitbucket.org/sjl/gundo.vim/issues/42/about-python3-support